# flex bison, tokenizing stops after encountering a token while reading from a file

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer

I am new to flex and bison. I am trying to write a simple grammar accepting the string :a word in lowercase followed by a word in upper case. below are my files-

file.l

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

int yywrap(void)
{
    printf("parsing is done*\n");   
    //yylex();
    //return 0;
}
%}

%%
[a-z]* { printf("found lower\n");
    yylval=yytext;
    return LOWER;
}
[A-Z]* { printf("found upper\n");
    yylval=yytext;
    return UPPER;
}

[ \n] ;
. ;
%%
void main()
{


        yyin = fopen("file.txt", "r");
        yylex();//this function will start the rules section.... it starts the parsing.....
        fclose(yyin);

}//main ends
```

file.y

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define YYSTYPE char *
int yylex(void);
void yyerror(const char *str)
{
        fprintf(stderr,"error: %s\n",str);
}
%}

%token LOWER UPPER

%%
start   :
    |
    start LOWER UPPER
    {
        printf("%s--%s\n",$2,$3);

    }
%%
```

contents of file.txt is:

token TOKEN

this is how i compile and run:

flex file.l

yacc -d file.y

gcc lex.yy.c y.tab.c -o file

./file

The program gives warning 
warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
yylval=yytext;

When I run the program (ignoring warning), the output is "found lower" i.e the program stops reading tokens after `return LOWER`. Can anyone help and tell me why is this running like this?Also why is the warning generated even though i specified `#define YYSTYPE char *` in file.y

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### 1. Why is the warning generated even though I specified `#define YYSTYPE char *` in `file.y`?

Because that define is not visible in `file.l`. Both files must have consistent definitions of`yytext`.

Also, you should be aware that it is never correct to simply set `yylval = yytext` because the buffer into which `yytext` points is part of a private data structure of the lexical scanner. If you need to pass the token's string value to the parser, you must make a copy.

#### 2. Why does `main` not read the whole file?

Because you are never actually calling the parser, whose name is `yyparse`. If you are using a standard bison parser, you should never call `yylex` directly; `yylex` is called by the parser when it needs a token. [Note 1]

Since `yylex` just returns a single token, calling it once will produce one token. You can call it in a loop, as suggested in a comment, but that will still not parse the file.

---

#### Notes

1. Bison can generate "push-parsers" which are called by the lexer when it has an available token. In that case, the lexer actions would not `return` until the entire input has been parsed, and you would call `yylex` rather than `yyparse`. That can simplify the parsing of certain languages, but it is certainly not the case here.

Comment: I got the solution. I changed the code in main function of file.l to yyin = fopen("file.txt", "r"); while(yylex()); fclose(yyin);  Now whole file is parsed. But output is "found lower   found upper   parsing is done******"  This time no output from file.y is produced. Does this mean that only tokenization is done and no parsing is done?How to do the parsing.

Comment: @RaKo: OK, now I've answered both your questions. Please read both suggestions and make sure you fix the issues with `yylval`; otherwise, you will end up with very mysterious-looking tokens in your parser.

Comment: part 2 explanation is great. I have got the solution. solution for part 1)#define YYSTYPE char * in the definition section of both file.l and file.y 2)the main function in file.l will be yyin = fopen("file.txt", "r");yyparse(); fclose(yyin);  Thanks for your help, I could not get this simple thing from anywhere else.